# Count distinct multiple columns in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to count rows which have a distinct combination of 2 columns in Amazon redshift. The query I am using is -

```
select count(distinct col1, col2)
from schemaname.tablename
where some filters
```

It is throwing me this error -

> Amazon Invalid operation: function count(character varying, bigint) does not exist`

I tried casting `bigint` to `char` but it didn't work.

Comment: please share your sample data and expected output

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. It would be great if could provide you whole use case. So we could try to find the best way for you

Comment: In Postgres you could use `select count (distinct (col1, col2))` (note the parentheses around the two columns)- maybe Redshift allows that as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, tried it.
It doesn't work even with parentheses around the column combination

Answer (score 37, accepted):

you can use sub-query and count

```
select count(*) from (
  select distinct col1, col2 
 from schemaname.tablename
  where some filter
) as t
```

Comment: I believe that this is also much better from a performance perspective in RedShift.

Answer (score 15):

A little late to the party but anyway: you can also try to concatenate columns using [|| operator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_concat_op.html). It might be inefficient so I wouldn't use it in prod code, but for ad-hoc analysis should be fine.

```
select count(distinct col1 || '_' || col2)
from schemaname.tablename
where some filters
```

Note separator choice might matter, i.e.
both `'foo' || '_' || 'bar_baz'` and `'foo_bar' || '_' || 'baz'` yield `'foo_bar_baz'` and are thus equal. In some cases this might be concern, in some it's so insignificant you can skip separator completely.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
select col1,col2,count(*) from schemaname.tablename
where -- your filter
group by col1,col2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to do `count(distinct)` then Zaynul's answer is correct.  If you want other aggregations as well, here is another method:

```
select . . ., 
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as col1_col2_unique_count
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col1) as seqnum
      from schemaname.tablename t
      where some filters
     ) c
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of the columns have `NULL`, then concatenation might be insufficient, and the result might be wrong.

I would suggest a combination of concatenation with **replacing `NULLs`** with the **empty string**, i.e.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT NVL(col1, '') || NVL (col2, '') || NVL (col3, ''))
```